# Get every word ending with dot using Regex/VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba, regex-group

In Office 2019 Excel spreadsheet.
I am trying to extract from any specified cell up to 5 words ending with dot after a ].

Sample text:

> some text [asred.] ost. |Monday - Ribben (ult.) lot. ac, sino. other maybe long text; collan.

I expect:

> ost. ult. lot. sino. collan.

I found this function on the internet:

```vb
Public Function RegExtract(Txt As String, Pattern As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    '.Global = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
    If .test(Txt) Then
        RegExtract = .Execute(Txt)(0)
    Else
        RegExtract = "No match found"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

I call it from an empty cell:

```
=RegExtract(D2; "([\]])(\s\w+[.]){0,5}")
```

My expression:

```
([\]])(\s\w+[.]){0,5}
```

It returns:

> ] ost.

1. I am not able to get rid of the ] which is needed to find the place where my useful bits start inside the text block, since \K does not work in Excel.
2. I don't understand how iterators work to get "up to 5 occurrences".
   I expected that {0,5} after the second group meant: repeat the previous group until the end of the text block (or until you manage to do it 5 times).

--Added after JdvD accepted answer for the records--

I am using this pattern to get all the words ending with dot, after the **first** occurrence of the closing bracket.

```
^.*?\]|(\w+\.\s?)|.
```

This one (without the question mark) instead gets all the words ending with dot, after the **last** occurrence of the closing bracket.

```
^.*\]|(\w+\.\s?)|.
```

I was missing something in my regExtract function: I needed to store the  matches into an array through a for loop and then output this array as a string. I was assuming that the regex engine was storing matches as a unique string.

The working function:

```vb
Public Function RegExtract(Txt As String, Pattern As String) As String

Dim rMatch As Object, arrayMatches(), i As Long

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
    If .Test(Txt) Then
        For Each rMatch In .Execute(Txt)
            If Not IsEmpty(rMatch.SubMatches(0)) Then
                ReDim Preserve arrayMatches(i)
                arrayMatches(i) = rMatch.SubMatches(0)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
        RegExtract = Join(arrayMatches, " ")
    Else
        RegExtract = "No match found"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RegexMatch:**

In addition to the answer given by [@RonRosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74383421/9758194) one could apply what some refer to as ['The Best Regex Trick Ever'](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) which would imply to first match what you **don't** want and then match what you **do** want in a capture group. For example:

```
^.*\]|(\w+\.)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EsB7G/1) where in short this means:

- `^.*\]` - Match 0+ (Greedy) characters from the start of the string upto the last occurence of closing square brackets;
- `|` - Or;
- `(\w+\.)` - Capture group holding 1+ (Greedy) word-characters ending with a dot.

Here is how it could work in an UDF:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "some text [asred.] ost. |Monday - Ribben (ult.) lot. ac, sino. other maybe long text; collan. "

Debug.Print RegExtract(s, "^.*\]|(\w+\.)")

End Sub

'------

'The above Sub would invoke the below function as an example.
'But you could also invoke this through: `=RegExtract(A1,"^.*\]|(\w+\.)")`
'on your sheet.

'------

Public Function RegExtract(Txt As String, Pattern As String) As String

Dim rMatch As Object, arrayMatches(), i As Long

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
    If .Test(Txt) Then
        For Each rMatch In .Execute(Txt)
            If Not IsEmpty(rMatch.SubMatches(0)) Then
                ReDim Preserve arrayMatches(i)
                arrayMatches(i) = rMatch.SubMatches(0)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
        RegExtract = Join(arrayMatches, " ")
    Else
        RegExtract = "No match found"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

---

**RegexReplace:**

Depending on your desired output one could also use a replace function. You'd have to match any remaining character with another alternative for that. For example:

```
^.*\]|(\w+\.\s?)|.
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/I526br/1) where in short this means that we added another alternative which is simply any single character. A 2nd small addition is that we added the option of an *optional* space character `\s?` in the 2nd alternative.

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "some text [asred.] ost. |Monday - Ribben (ult.) lot. ac, sino. other maybe long text; collan. "

Debug.Print RegReplace(s, "^.*\]|(\w+\.\s?)|.", "$1")

End Sub

'------

'There are now 3 parameters to parse to the UDF; String, Pattern and Replacement.

'------

Public Function RegReplace(Txt As String, Pattern As String, Replacement) As String

Dim rMatch As Object, arrayMatches(), i As Long

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
    RegReplace = Trim(.Replace(Txt, Replacement))
End With

End Function
```

Note that I used `Trim()` to remove possible trailing spaces.

---

Both RegexMatch and RegexReplace would currently return a single string to clean the input but the former does give you the option to deal with the array in the arrayMatches() variable.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your exahustive answer, and neat trick! I can tell that the function works as expected, but I noticed that in the blobs of text to clean up I sometimes have other square brackets. Is it possible to fix the expression to negate everything before the first occurrence of ] (not the last as it works now) ? Thank you!

Comment: Silly me! I just needed to remove .* from your negation pattern! :)

Comment: @Serbiss I think you should change `^.*\]` into a lazy pattern using `^.*?\]`

Comment: do you think there is some advange using one solution (^\]) over the other  ( ^.*?\] ) ? Both appear to work

Comment: If you show me the exact pattern you used I could. Because simply `^\]` is only matching a closing bracket directly at the beginning of a string.

Comment: @JcdV of course, it's your pattern :)  `"^\]|(\w+\.\s?)|."` VS  `"^.*?\]|(\w+\.\s?)|."`

Comment: Yes, use the 2nd one. The 1st one won't work for what you need @Serbiss. It may work on one string but gives you false result on another

Comment: This is not the method I couldn't recall, but it is much simpler than that method. Thanks for posting.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, your welcome. Makes me curious as to what you've seen before though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method to return all the matches in a string starting after a certain pattern.  But I can't recall it at this time.

In the meantime, it seems the simplest would be to remove everything prior to the first `]`, and then apply Regex to the remainder.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub findit()
  Const str As String = "some text [asred.] ost. |Monday - Ribben (ult.) lot. ac, sino. other maybe long text; collan."
  Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
  Dim S As String
  Dim sOutput As String
  
S = Mid(str, InStr(str, "]"))

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Pattern = "\w+(?=\.)"
    .Global = True
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        For Each M In MC
            sOutput = sOutput & vbLf & M
        Next M
    End If
End With


MsgBox Mid(sOutput, 2)

End Sub
```

*You could certainly limit the number of matches to 5 by using a counter instead of the `For each` loop*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't thought about a for loop to store all the matches! I marked JvdV as best answer because it covers everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\.
```

Let me explain a little bit.

`[a-zA-Z]` - this looks for anything that contain any letter from a to z and A to Z, but it only matches the first letter.

`\+` - with this you are telling that matches all the letters until it finds something that is not a letter from a to z and A to Z

`\.` - with this you are just looking for the . at the end of the match

Here the [example](https://regex101.com/r/qunuZq/1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is indeed another way to do it (but I still need to find the first closing square bracket)